# How to get mp3 files form Saavn app

Tags: applications, mp3

I am using [Saavn](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.saavn.android&hl=en) for listening to and downloading music. The problem is that the app downloads all of its data to my internal storage. I have only 8GB of storage in which only 5.23GB is user usable.

Now the cache size of Saavn is more than 2GB. I don't have space to install new apps but I don't want to delete the songs.

I tried to move the mp3 files. I navigated to the `Android > Data > com.saavn > songs` folder and found mp3 files whose names are random 10+ digit numbers. When I try to play these files My music players is unable to play them. I even tried other apps like N7 Music Player.

Is there any way by which I can either extract the mp3 files or I can change the storage to SD card? I see no option for this in Saavn.

Comment: You can play the `curr.mp3` which is the currently playing offline song. Other offline downloaded song will be encrypted so you can't play with other players. Also, see [Saavn downloader](http://addtotech.com/blog/saavn-downloader-download-mp3/). Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Gx5uhS-3Kk) for more ;)

Answer (score 1):

It will vary depending on your phone and version of android. But in Settings>Applications>Saavn you should find a `Move to SD` button which will move the app and its data to the SD card.

If the app was preinstalled on your phone the button will not be there since the app probably cannot be moved out of the system partition. In which case, I recommend clearing the app's cache and using a different service that can be installed on the SD card.

Answer (score 0):

You can not play that file because those files are encrypted.
So the names of those files will be like fhADdff.mp3 or any name with alphabetic or numerical digit.

So, first of all play the file in the Saavn music app which you have add to the offline mode in saavn for some seconds.
After that go to the ES file Explorer or any explorer and find the folder `com.saavn.android/songs` (typically under `/data/data`).
In that folder there would be file with name curr.mp3 which is the file you have played in saavn offline mode.
Copy that file in any folder and rename it.
Now you can play this file in other music player..